# Possible to have AWS health check a page?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I'd like our Route53 AWS health check to check the health of a page, not necessarily a directory (Example: http://xxx.xx.xxxx:80/)

Is this possible? The reason being, if our lighttpd server goes down or say wordpress crashes the server, etc; having it check just a directory (Example: http://xxx.xx.xxxx:80/) may not return a 500 error....but our app will be down.

Can I have it check http://xxx.xx.xxxx:80/Page/index.php instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Amazon Route 53](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/) doesn't prevent you to check a 'page', to the contrary, it only cares about the path being a regular HTTP endpoint/resource returning respective [HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), see e.g. [Creating Health Checks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-creating.html):

> **Path (HTTP Only)**
>   The path that you want Route 53 to request when
>   performing health checks. The path can be any value for which your
>   endpoint will return an HTTP status code of 2xx or 3xx when the
>   endpoint is healthy, for example, the file
>   /docs/route53-health-check.html. Note that the leading / is required.

Please also be aware of the detailed health check specifics outlined on [Managing Resource Availability with Route 53 Failover](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks.html), which might affect your testing/production results, e.g. for *HTTP health checks*:

> - **HTTP health checks**: Route 53 must be able to establish a TCP connection with the endpoint within four seconds, and the endpoint
>     must respond with an HTTP status code of less than 400 within two
>     seconds.
> - **All health checks**: For a health check to change from healthy to unhealthy, it must fail three consecutive times. For a health check to
>     change from unhealthy to healthy, it must pass three consecutive
>     times.

Comment: Enable String matching as well so you're checking not only 2xx/3xx response status but also the response payload.